# Instance member "xxx" cannot be used on type "XXX" - Specifically iOS Swift 4 Tutorial on Workout Extensions

Tags: ios, swift

First of all, I have read through some of "similar" enquiry, but none seem to specifically describe the issue I encountered. Most are Swift 3 and earlier, which I am currently unable to comprehend. Please pardon my small request to sought for some help here.

```
struct Workout {
    var distance: Double
    var time: Double
    var averageHR: Int
}

extension Workout: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "\(distance) metres at \(time) seconds with HR \(averageHR)"
    }


}

extension Workout {
    static var speed: Double {
        return distance / time
    }


    func harderWorkout() -> Workout {
        let newDist = distance * 2
        let newTime = time * 2
        let newAverageHR = averageHR + 40
        return Workout(distance: newDist, time: newTime, averageHR: newAverageHR)
    }
}
```

The question asked in the tutorial is "Now create another extension for Workout and add a property speed of type Double. It should be a computed property that returns the average meters per second traveled during the workout."

And that's where I'm stuck, to specifically go according to the instructions given. The best I can do is to create a workaround using a static func instead

```
static func calculateSpeed(distance: Double, time: Double) -> Double {
        var speed: Double {
        return distance / time
        }
        return speed
    }
```

But it seem forced. Would anyone know what would be the "correct" way to actually solve this? I think is more of how to compute the properties within the structure, which I am unable to recall or search for any answers. I really appreciate any help rendered.

Comment: Simply remove the "static" in `static var speed` ... that must have been answered before!

Comment: hi thanks for the help. i don't really understand your solution though, because it asked to add a property "speed" of type Double for the extension.

Comment: ok. i think i got it. pardon my rashness to comment first before changing my code. but may i know why it works when the "static" is removed?

Comment: `static var speed` defines a *type property* and `var speed` an *instance property.* It is explained in the linked-to Q&A. You'll also find it in the Swift language reference in the chapter about properties.

Comment: yup. i was editing my previous reply when your prompt response was updated. Thank you so much for the quick and precise search which I was unable to do. Both your's and the link explained it well!